# If $Y\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i$ and $\overset{°}Y\neq\varnothing$ and $\overset{°}Y\cap X_i=\varnothing$ whether $Y\neq X_i$ then $Y=X_i$

Tags: general-topology

> **Statement** 1
>
> If $\mathfrak{X}=\{X_i:i\in I\}$ is a collection of not empty set and if there exist a set $Y$ such that $Y\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i$ and $\overset{°}Y\neq\varnothing$ and if  $\overset{°}Y\cap X_i=\varnothing$ for any $i\in I$ such that $Y\neq X_i$ then $Y=X_i$ for some $i\in I$.
>
> *Proof*. If $Y\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$ then if was $\overset{°}Y\cap X_i=\varnothing$ for any $i\in I$ then by hypothesis of the sets $X_i$ it would be or $\overset{°}Y=\varnothing$ or $\overset{°}Y\subseteq X^C_i$ for any $i\in I$ and so $\overset{°}Y\subseteq\bigcap_{i\in I}X^C_i=\Big(\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i\Big)^C$ and clearly both results are incompatible with the hypotheses and so for some $i\in I$ it is $\overset{°}Y\cap X_i\neq\varnothing$ and so $Y=X_i$.
>
> **Statement** 2
>
> If $\mathfrak{X}=\{X_i:i\in I\}$ is a collection of not empty set such that $\overset{°}X_i\neq\varnothing$ and if there exist a set $Y\neq\varnothing$ such that $Y\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i$ and if  $Y\cap\overset{°}X_i=\varnothing$ for any $i\in I$ such that $Y\neq X_i$ then $Y=X_i$ for some $i\in I$.

Unfortunately I can't pove the second statement so I ask if it is true and so or to give a couterexample or to prove it. Then I ask if the the proof of the first statement is correct. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work in $\Bbb R$. For $n\in\Bbb Z$ let $X_n=[n,n+1)$, and let $Y=\Bbb Z$. Clearly $\operatorname{int}X_n=(n,n+1)$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z$, $\varnothing\ne Y\subseteq\Bbb R=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z}X_n$, $Y\cap\operatorname{int}X_n=\varnothing$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$, and $Y\ne X_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Okay, I understand your counterexample: so the second statement is generally false. Rather what can you say about the first statement? is it true? is my proof correct?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: It’s correct, but you don’t need to split off the case $\operatorname{int}Y=\varnothing$: that’s included in the case $\operatorname{int}Y\subseteq X\setminus\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$ if for convenience you take $X=\bigcup\mathfrak{X}$, which you might as well do. The hypothesis that either $Y=X_i$ or $X_i\cap\operatorname{int}Y=\varnothing$ for each $i\in I$ is **very** strong.

Comment: Umm...in truth the hypothesis I give is that $\overset{°}Y\cap X_i=\emptyset$ for each $i\in I$ such that $Y\neq X_i$ and so from this I want to prove that $Y=X_i$ for some $i\in I$. So I don't understand very well what you want to  say in the last part of your comment: could you explain better, please? Excuse me: forgive my confusion.

Comment: @Antonio: Your hypothesis is equivalent to the one that I stated. Yours is that for each $i\in I$, if $Y\ne X_i$, then $X_i\cap\operatorname{int}Y=\varnothing$. This has the form $\forall i\in I(\varphi(i)\to\psi)$. But $\forall i\in I(\varphi(i)\to\psi)$ is logically equivalent to $\forall i\in I(\neg\varphi(i)\lor\psi)$, which in this case is that for each $i\in I$, either $Y=X_i$ or $X_i\cap\operatorname{int}Y=\varnothing$.

Comment: Okay, thanks too much!!! Excuse me for yesterday, but I musted still to  understand whicht was the hyoptheses that imply the statement.

Comment: @Antonio: You’re welcome!